# Empty dialog boxes in unity apps

Tags: 16.04, unity, desktop-environments

I had install unity8 then uninstall it again, now i have empty boxes in every unity dialog like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now i just change the theme to a new one 'Numix' for example. and everything is cool